# Where can I find Ferris enemies in Gormott?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-2

One of Pyra’s affinity challenges is to defeat 6 Ferris enemies in Gormott. (Excluding unique monsters). I’ve searched all over Gormott Province, but the few I’ve been able to find were level 30 or higher.

Where in Gormott can I find Ferris enemies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I remember there are two different sets of Feris enemies in Gormott. The level 30 ones you mentioned and some lower level (about 8 - 10, not sure) which include a unique enemy.

The higher level ones can be found in upper red circle and the lower ones are on and around a rock formation in the lower red circle.
There are two types; [Leo Feris](http://xenoblade.wikia.com/wiki/Leo_Feris) and [Young Feris](http://xenoblade.wikia.com/wiki/Young_Feris)

[image: gormott]